# Internet issues system-wide after 21.04

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, 21.04

For the past 3 months, my internet has been working fine.
I have an Ubuntu/Windows 10 Dualboot.
However, I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04.
Immediately, during the installation process, my internet started cutting out about every 2-4 hours and I had to reconnect.
This hadn't happened since I bought this Wifi card 3 months ago.
And every day, this problem has gotten worse. Now I have around 3-15 minutes before it disconnects, and what's worse is that my internet doesn't work at all on Windows anymore. And also, it's not disconnecting in the sense that it's leaving the network - It's still connected, but it can't transmit any data.

Also after the installation, my internet speed slowly dropped. Before the installation, it was around 80MB/S, but now it's only 250KB/S. If this goes on too much longer I'll have sub-dialup internet that disconnects every few seconds.

This is especially scary because I use this computer for school.
What's worse is that this is the only computer on the network that does this, and the router being restarted seems to speed up the "degrading" of the internet.

COMPUTER SPECS:

Model: HP Z220 SFF Workstation (upgraded to handle midrange gaming)

CPU: Intel Core I5 Ivy Bridge @ 3.2GHZ

Hard Drive: WDC-WD10EZEX 1TB (40% full)

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

WiFi Card: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.04/Windows 10

P.S: My internet did the thing twice during the writing of this.

P.P.S: After digging around in the syslog, it looks like a combination from it randomly renaming itself between wls1 and wlan0 and a daemon or task named rfkill0.

P.P.P.S: After more digging, the answer is actually quite frightening and I don't know how to fix it. It seems as though the Wi-Fi card dies and the computer has to detect the card again.

Comment: The timing of the fault's emergence may be a coincidence. Check /var/log/syslog for wi-fi-related and hardware-related error messages.

Comment: Thanks, but the file is massive. How do I look for internet-related problems in this file only?

Comment: Most of the file contents are likely related to your problem. The same cascade of errors, repeating over and over and over. Read it line-by-line until you understand the pattern.

Comment: I'm not joking, according to the log it's hinting towards it randomly renaming itself between wlan0 and wls1

Comment: I've found the root cause, which is the card literally dying and the computer finding it again and turning it back on. How do I fix this?

Comment: What you are describing seems like a hardware fault. If so, replace the hardware. Ubuntu is not designed to run with faulty hardware, and cannot compensate for it.

Comment: This card costed 25 dollars though and I spent my monthly allowance on something else, and it took a good few days to arrive.

Comment: Look for others with that hardware reporting similar problems, and what they did about it. Look into the vendor's return or exchange policy. Ask friends and family whom you respect for their advice. You have discovered that the issue is not Ubuntu, so we reached our limit here.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `uname -r`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.